# Showing that a sequence of a cofibration is exact.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence, cofibrations

The question is :

Suppose that $A \rightarrow B$ is a cofibration with cofiber $C.$ Show that for any pointed space $X,$ the sequence $[C,X] \rightarrow [B,X] \rightarrow [A,X]$ is an exact sequence of pointed sets.

**My professor answer started with:**

"if $A \xrightarrow{\text{i}} B \xrightarrow{\text{q}} B/A$ is a cofibre sequence " but I do not know why he started by this statement, does every cofibre sequence  has the inclusion map and the quotient map into $B/A,$ could anyone explain this for me please?

Also, the definition of cofibration in AT does not say the above, may be he is using pg.398 in AT, I do not know.

Comment: Can you share more context?

Comment: what other information do you want @Berci? I am sharing the question and the first sentence in the answer

Comment: What does "AT" stand for?

Comment: Every cofibration $i\colon A \to B$ is in particular an embedding with closed image, and the cofibre aka mapping cone $C$ is homotopy equivalent to $B/A$.

Comment: @William what do you mean by "closed image"?

Comment: @William a cofibration is an embedding but need not have closed image (take the inclusion of the open point in the Sierpinski space).

Comment: A cofibration is a closed embedding whenever the codomain is separated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terminology some people use is to reserve the term *cofibre sequence*, or *strict cofibre sequence*, for something of the form

$$A\xrightarrow{i} B\xrightarrow{q} B/A$$

where $i$ is a cofibration (i.e. has the HEP) and $q$ is the quotient. Sequences of this form have the nice property that *strict* equality holds for the composition

$$q\circ i=\ast.$$

That this equality holds strictly makes working with these spaces an maps more easy in many applications.

On the other hand, we can turn any map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ into a cofibration by replacing it with the inclusion of $X$ into the mapping cyclinder $M_f$ of $f$. This gives us a strict cofibre sequence

$$X\xrightarrow{i_f} M_f\xrightarrow{q_f} M_f/i_f(X).$$

Here $M_f=Y\sqcup X\times I/[f(x)\sim (x,0)]$, and $i_f$ is the map $x\mapsto (x,1)$. You can check easily that $i_f$ is a cofibration. We can also identify the quotient

$$M_f/i_f(X)=C_f=Y\sqcup CX/[f(x)\sim (x,0)]$$

with the mapping cone $C_f$ of $f$ (here $CX=X\times I/X\times 1)$.

Now there is an obvious inclusion $Y\hookrightarrow M_f$ which turns out to be a deformation retract. The point is that *up to identification by homotopy* we can write the second sequence above as

$$X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{q} C_f$$

This is what some authors would call a *homotopy cofibre sequence*. Compared to the above sequences we now have only the relation of null-homotopy

$$q\circ f\simeq \ast$$

rather than the *strict* equality in the previous cases. Note however, that there is a *canonical* null-homotopy of this composition (just slide up the cone in $C_f$).

Of course, if we are working at the level of homotopy, then really this is all we need: strict equality is essentially meaningless here. Hence a lot of authors will call both types of sequences above simply *cofibre sequences*, and not make any distinction between the two, since it doesn't really effect things at the level of homotopy.

So, to answer your question, let us *define* a cofiber sequence to be a pair, consisting of a sequence

$$X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}Z$$

of spaces and maps, together with a choice of null-homotopy $\psi:g\circ f\simeq \ast$, such that the map $\theta_\psi:C_f\rightarrow Z$ induced by $\psi$ is a homotopy equivalence.

This definition encompasses both the previous constructions, and with it not every cofibre sequence is exactly a subspace inclusion followed by a quotient map, but every cofibre sequence is *equivalent* to one of this form (in a sense you will come to understand more precisely in your lectures).