# A follow up to "Showing that a sequence of a cofibration is exact"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, exact-sequence, cofibrations

After reading through the explanation that Tyrone gave on this page [Showing that a sequence of a cofibration is exact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563711/showing-that-a-sequence-of-a-cofibration-is-exact)

I am curious on how one would use that information to fully prove that if $A \rightarrow B$ is a cofibration with cofiber $C$, then for any pointed space $X,$ the sequence $[C,X] \rightarrow [B,X] \rightarrow [A,X]$ is an exact sequence of pointed sets.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $C_f$ is obtained from $B$ and $CA:=A\times[0,1]/A\times\{1\}$ by identifying $(a,0)\in CA$ with $f(a)\in B$. Next, recall that Tyrone defines a cofiber sequence as follows

> A *cofiber sequence* is a sequence $A\xrightarrow fB\xrightarrow gC$, together with an homotopy $H:gf\rightarrow *$ such that the induced map $\chi:C_f\rightarrow C$ is an homotopy equivalence.

In particular, since we're looking at homotopy classes of maps, precomposition with $\chi$ induces an isomorphism $$[C,X]\xrightarrow\simeq [C_f,X]$$ and the sequence $[C,X]\rightarrow [B,X]\rightarrow [A,X]$ is equivalent to $[C_f,X]\rightarrow[B,X]\xrightarrow{f_*}[A,X]$, so we only need to show exactness of the latter to derive exactness of the former.

It should be clear now how you conclude exactness from this property of $C_f$: Since $C_f$ is obtained by gluing $B$ and $CA$, a morphism $C_f\rightarrow X$ is equivalent to morphisms $\beta:B\rightarrow X$ and $\alpha:CA\rightarrow X$ that are compatible with the way $B$ and $CA$ are glued, meaning $$\beta(f(a))=\alpha(a,0)$$Moreover, since $CA$ is obtained by taking $A\times I$ and collapsing $A\times\{1\}$ to a point, a morphism $\alpha:CA\rightarrow X$ is equivalent to a morphism $H:A\times I\rightarrow X$ such that $H(-,1)=*$ (in this general scenario, $*$ need not be the point of $X$, but in the proof of exactness it will be), hence an homotopy between $*$ and $H(-,0)=\alpha(-,0)=\beta\circ f$. Do you see how to conclude?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your explanation was very intuitive. I may ask, what would the process entail to conclude?

Comment: Just opening up the definitions: If you have $h:B\rightarrow X$ representing an homotopy class in the kernel of $f_*:[B,X]\rightarrow [A,X]$, this means that $hf$ is homotopic to the constant value $*$ (the base point of $X$), but then you have $h$, you have the homotopy $H:hf\rightarrow *$, glue them together and you get $k:C_f\rightarrow X$ that precomposite with $B\rightarrow C_f$ is equal to $f$ (by definition)